# Create file to download js

Tags: javascript, file, download

I'm receiving a JSON output from an API, and i want to use it with JS and also save that output to file. Is there any way to trigger the browser download machanism using JS with thet output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe now some browsers support the attribute `download` but you don't trigger the browser to automatically download the file.

the only way i know is @BAS's solution but without a filename.

tested in chrome ..

```
array=[{a:'1',b:'2'},{x:'3',y:'4'}];

function dl(array,filename){
 var b=document.createElement('a');
 b.download=filename;
 b.textContent=filename;
 b.href='data:application/json;base64,'+
 window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(array))))
 // or 
 // b.href='data:application/javascript;charset=utf-8,'+JSON.stringify(json);
 return b
}

document.body.appendChild(dl(array,'my.json'));
```

example

http://jsfiddle.net/8yQcW/

**UPDATE direct download works** ... on chrome i tested.

on append simulate click

```
var e=document.createEvent('Events');
    e.initEvent('click',true,false);
    document.getElementById('dl').dispatchEvent(e);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8yQcW/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with a data URI:

```
function triggerDownload(json) {
 var dataUri = 'data:text;charset=utf-8,' + json;
 window.open(dataUri);
}
```

Try entering `data:text;charset=utf-8,{"Key":"Value"}` into your browsers address bar. It should show you the save dialog.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for more information and browser support.