# how to save a value from textarea to a blank file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, autosave

I'm making a webpage wherein a user can make his/her own functions, then those functions will become like an option to the side of the webpage so when they are click/selected they can be used. Here's the flow

1. User creates function written in js
2. when save button is click it will automatically be save to Savedfunction.js file
3. the created function will be called as a checkbox so that it can be use

Here's a picture to further elaborate the problem:

[image]

Comment: Are you saving this stuff to a server somewhere, or is it just being 'saved'/executed in the browser?

Comment: @sir jameslafferty it is saved locally or in the computer

Comment: _locally or in the computer_. Isn't that the same?

Comment: In that case, look here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ or on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGuide/API/File_System?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FAPI%2FFile+System

Comment: yes no sir what I mean is it is save in my computer but it can also be save to our local area network (LAN)

Comment: AFAIK you cannot write a local file with JavaScript.

Comment: @Palec That's not quite correct. You can write to a local file using the File API. It's not implemented across all browsers, but it does exist.

Comment: @jameslafferty I have to update my JS knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all javascript can't save files on you computer (except you use ie).  security,privacy...**

---

**If you want to let the user download his created file:**

Chrome has the new `download` attribute 
but it works also on other brosers without the download attribute.

```
var txt='var x = 3,lol=fun;';

function dl(data,filename){
 var b=document.createElement('a');
 b.download=filename;
 b.textContent=filename;
 b.href='data:application/json;base64,'+
 window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
 return b
}

document.body.appendChild(dl(txt,'my.js'));
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/8yQcW/

in the comment is also a link for automatic download.

---

**Want to save the data on your server:**

note:if you want to save the function to the server you need a server language like php

```
<?php
if($_POST['fn']&&$_POST['data']){
 $fh=fopen($_POST['fn'],'w') or die("can't open file");
 if(fwrite($fh,$_POST['data'])){
  echo '["ok":"file saved"]';// maybe return the saved code.
  //echo json_encode($_POST);
 }else{
  echo '["error":"can\'t save the file"]';
 }
 fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

---

**Want to save the data only on the users computer (using modern web technologies?)**

you can also store the data inside (clientSide):

```
window.localStorage
window.sessionStorage

webSQL

indexedDB
```

---

**Want to execute the script from it's string?**

don't use `eval();`

use:

```
 var js="var x='hey';alert(x);"
 (new Function(js))()
```

---

*To achieve what you need you need to mix this technologies.*

if you have any other questions just ask.

Comment: But you have to download it first?

Comment: the question is : "how to save a value from textarea to a blank file?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20327619/2450730 this explains also how it downloads the file automatically

Comment: Yes the title does, but OP wants it automatically to be saved and integrated in the website.

Comment: now my answer should give him all the hints he needs ... right?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the a kind of trick, **(the concept)**:

1. Add a code in php, or some other server side.
2. Post the script to the server side (POST method is the preffered one).
3. On the server side, write the whole page with the script - the php page will be with the javascript.
4. Redirect to the new page (the php/asp, or whatever best fit your needs).

Good luck !!!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can't write directly to the file system (unless you use a windows HTA application, running HTML/javascript - then special file system objects become available in IE). If this is appropriate, have a look here :
[Microsoft FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Assuming it's a traditional web page, it'll need to save the resulting javascript to the Savedfunction.js file.

That's just a text file, so you could have ..

- User adds new javascript as simple text in a textarea on your web page.
- When the user commits the new function (ie clicks 'save' or whatever), submit the HTML form  to the server.
- Have the recieving script on server amend the file and add it to the js file

That is : A normal submit process, just appending to a file, which happens to be a javascript file. If any need parameters, then you might also need to keep a list of functions generated and the text of a legitemate call to them- otherwise how can the user (or web page) know how to use them ?

To view the javascript functions available, open the web page which reads (via server script) your js file for data on what to present ain the menu options, and also include the js file as a script so that clicking the right option runs the right javascript routine.

As for syntax checking when you submit the javascript .. I'll leave that bit up to you ! I guess you could use window.eval (wrapped in try .. catch block) to see if it compiled before submitting.